# Grails: URL mapping - how to pass file extension?

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I have some folder with different files.
I want to use something like this: http://myserver.com/foo/bar/test.html

I'm using this way to obtain path:

```
"/excursion/$path**" (controller:"excursion", action:"sweet")
```

But it doesn't helps with file extensions... How to disable file extensions truncating ?

P.S.

```
class ExcursionController {
 def defaultAction = "sweet"

 def sweet = {
  render "${params.path}"
 }
}
```

Request http://myserver.com/excursion/foo/bar/test.html

The result is "foo/bar/test" with no extension :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what does

```
render "${params.path}.${request.format}"
```

give you?

Answer (score 2):

Disable file extension truncation by adding this line to `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy`:

```
grails.mime.file.extensions = false
```

This impacts content negotiation, so I suggest you read section 7.8 of the Grails [user guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#contentNegotiation)