# Grails HTTP Proxy

Tags: grails, proxy, url-mapping

I want to create a proxy controller in grails, something that just takes whatever is passed in based on a url mapping, records what was asked for, sends the request to another server, records the response, and send the response back to the browser.

I'm having trouble with when the request has an odd file extension (.gif) or no file extension (/xxx?sdcscd)

My url mapping is:

```
"/proxy/$target**"
```

and I've attempted (per an answer to another question):

```
def targetURL = params.target
if (!FilenameUtils.getExtension(targetURL) && request.format) {
    targetURL += ".${response.format}"
}
```

but this usually appends .html and never the .gif or ?csdcsd

Not sure what to do as I might just write the thing in straight Java

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the real answer was sitting in the [post you linked to previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552215/grails-url-mapping-how-to-pass-file-extension) all along, by Peter Ledbrook:

> Disable file extension truncation by adding this line to `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy`:
>
> ```
> grails.mime.file.extensions = false
> ```

This will disable the usage of file extensions for format, but will leave the file extension on `params.target`.  You can completely ignore `response.format`!